# Polymer Integration with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, polymer, erb

I am trying to use polymer in rails. In normal HTML polymer elements can be imported by using the link rel='import tag of Html but how do I do the equivalent of this in .erb. Or is there any other way of directly using polymer in rails without using any third party gem? I have all the polymer elements in vendor/assets/bower_components. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "emcee" gem.
It allow you to use components (.html elements done with polymer) like normal assets (.js, .css)
Enjoy ;)
https://github.com/ahuth/emcee
[Google Polymer with rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884022/google-polymer-with-rails-4)